# Cannot add class to eclipse oxygen project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

I can't add groovy and/java classes to groovy project in Eclipse Oxygen.

**Session Data:**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
java.version=9.0.4
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_ZA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/yodaqua/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data file:/Users/yodaqua/ks-test-automation/workspace-lib/jenkins-pipeline-script-development/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/yodaqua/.eclipse_keyring
```

**Steps:**

1. I installed the latest Eclipse Oxygen
2. then add Java Development Tools
3. then added Groovy (http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.7)
4. then created a groovy project
5. then converted it to a maven project
6. then tried to add a groovy class and/or a java class.
7. I get: **Unhandled event loop exception**

**Stack Trace:**

```
Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.<init>(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration;Ljava/security/CodeSource;Lgroovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader;Lgroovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader;ZLjava/lang/String;)V
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyParser.newCompilationUnit(GroovyParser.java:121)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyParser.<init>(GroovyParser.java:111)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.internal.MultiplexingCommentRecorderParser.<init>(MultiplexingCommentRecorderParser.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.internal.MultiplexingCommentRecorderParser.<init>(MultiplexingCommentRecorderParser.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.internal.GroovyLanguageSupport.getParser(GroovyLanguageSupport.java:101)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.LanguageSupportFactory.getParser(LanguageSupportFactory.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.parse(CompilationUnitResolver.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.internalCreateAST(ASTParser.java:1227)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:823)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.TypeContextChecker.parseSuperType(TypeContextChecker.java:749)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.TypeContextChecker.parseSuperClass(TypeContextChecker.java:724)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage.superClassChanged(NewTypeWizardPage.java:1855)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage.typePageDialogFieldChanged(NewTypeWizardPage.java:1154)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage.access$2(NewTypeWizardPage.java:1118)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage$TypeFieldsAdapter.dialogFieldChanged(NewTypeWizardPage.java:1053)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.DialogField.dialogFieldChanged(DialogField.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.StringDialogField.setText(StringDialogField.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage.setSuperClass(NewTypeWizardPage.java:1402)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage.initTypePage(NewTypeWizardPage.java:627)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewClassWizardPage.init(NewClassWizardPage.java:92)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.wizards.NewClassWizard.addPages(NewClassWizard.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
        at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4258)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1502)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1525)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1510)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1314)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4082)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3699)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```

Please help :)

Thanks

Comment: whats `Java Development Tools`?

Comment: it's an eclipse plugin

Comment: Moved to and paid for IntelliJ. Best decision I made.